# beautifulsoup object is not callable

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I want to parse a website. However I have a behavior that I can't really explain : I get the soup through the beautifulSoup website. It is a bs4 element. However when I want to find all the mentionned balise, it says that the type of the element is None. Please find the code below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2 as web

url = "http://www.stevegtennis.com/men-atp-rankings/2015-7-6/1/all/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(web.urlopen(url).read(),'lxml')
print type(soup)
player1 = soup.findall('tr',class_="row1")
```

It returns the following error:

```
TypeError : 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Help much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean:

```
player1 = soup.find_all('tr',class_="row1")
```

rather than `soup.findall`. You don't get a `NameError` because BeautifulSoup implements `__getattr__` to return computed attributes and this returns `None` if it doesn't have the one you ask for.

Comment: Obviously :) Thanks very much : I did not pay attention to that, my mistake. It does work now. Thanks again

Comment: @Dirty_Fox you should mark the answer above since it solved your problem. He deserves a credit there.